# net use maps to wrong user on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, batch-file, mapped-drive

I have a Batch script that I need to run with elevated rights (starting Services etc.). This script also does `net use g: \\network\path`. But because I run the batch file as Administrator the mapped drives are only available in a cmd.exe with Admin rights. But I need it to be availabe on Explorer accessible from my regular user account.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming that you are not logging into a domain*

Create a file called "login.bat" containing the following command. 
net use g: \\foo\bar 
You may save this in the user's profile (eg: c:\users\username\documents)

Under the account properties point "Login Script:" under User Profile to c:\users\username\documents\login.bat. This may be found by doing the following.

*Assuming Windows 7*

1) Click start

2) Right click computer

3) Click 'manage"

4) Select Local Users and Groups under Computer Management

5) Select Users

6) Double Click the user you would like to add the script to / modify

7) Click the profile tab

8) Enter the information required into the "Logon script:" text box.

*side note*

The reason the drive was only mapping within the command prompt is because the instance was running under Administrator and network drives are mapped under "HKCU\Network" for each account's instance of logon.

If you require specific applications to run with admin rights on a specific user account you may want to look into account permissions instead as all applications run will run with the current user's level of privilege unless invoked by the system first.

Comment: But I do not want to run the batch script on logon! I want to run whenever I wish to. Or did I misinterpret the term "logon script"? The calling of `net use` in my script also depends on other things happening in the batch file (that definitely should not happen on logon time).